# Why `AVCaptureDevice` behaviour differently if the point is extactly (0.5, 0.5)?

Tags: ios, iphone, video, camera, video-capture

We using following code to set the exposure point of `AVCaptureDevice`. It works great most of the time.

But if the point `x` and `y` both is `0.5`, this values seams will reset the configuration, and the exposure behaviour differently. Currently we workaround this by detect the parameter, if it is `0.5`, we passing `0.501` instead `0.5` for this case.

We don't know why this happening? So any documents about that?

```
314         if([device lockForConfiguration:&err]) {
315             [device setExposurePointOfInterest:CGPointMake(x, y)];
316             device.exposureMode = device.exposureMode;
317             [device unlockForConfiguration];
318         }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess what you are seeing is default behaviour check [AVFoundation Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH5-SW14) --> look for **Exposure Modes**

> If you change the exposure settings, you can return them to the
>   default configuration as follows:
>
> ```
> if ([currentDevice isExposureModeSupported:AVCaptureExposureModeContinuousAutoExposure]){`
>     `CGPoint exposurePoint = CGPointMake(0.5f, 0.5f);`
>     `[currentDevice setExposurePointOfInterest:exposurePoint];`
>     `[currentDevice setExposureMode:AVCaptureExposureModeContinuousAutoExposure];`
> }
> ```

Comment: Thanks. But seams we set it as (0.5, 0.5) the video is much bright than (0.501, 0.501), strange behaviour.